# Monitor FTP on IIS 8.5 and run script upon upload

Tags: powershell, ftp, automation, iis

I'm running IIS 8.5 on Windows Server 2012 R2.
Is it possible to monitor an ftp account and if a certain type of file is uploaded EG. *.jpg or *.png, fire a powershell script automatically to compress/optimize the file?

Thanks.

Edit. I've been toying with the System.IO.FileSystemWatcher object to monitor folders and then batch optimize them at a given time. But I'm not too keen on this idea (see my comment below). But this is what I've got so far.

The monitoring script

```
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "C:\WebSites"
$watcher.Filter = "*.jpg"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

$action = { $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
            $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
            $logline = "$(Get-Date), $changeType, $path"
            Write-Host $path, $changeType
            Add-content "C:\Testing\log.txt" -value $path
            }    

Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action

while ($true) {sleep 5}
```

And then this script would be run via the Task Scheduler at a given time:

```
$A = $(foreach ($line in Get-Content "C:\Testing\log.txt")
{$line}) | sort | Get-Unique
Clear-Content "C:\Testing\log.txt"

& 'E:\Program Files\FileOptimizer\FileOptimizer64.exe'  $A /JPEGCopyMetadata=false/JPEGUseArithmeticEncoding=false/JPEGAllowLossy=true/ProcessPriority=128/DoNotCreateBackups=true
```

Comment: Hi there thanks for the response. I'm trying to optimize images uploaded to our server. The general idea is to monitor when someone uploads a .jpg or a .png and then run something like FileOptimizer via Powershell to compress the uploaded files. Been playing with the System.IO.FileSystemWatcher object to monitor folders, compile a list, then batch optimize at a given time. But this seems like over-kill to me. And would prefer to have something fire up either when a file is uploaded, or preferably when a FTP session ends and optimize all files during that session. I'll edit my post to demo.

Comment: Nice edit and detail with what you are trying. Seems like you're on the right track. I suppose you'd have to read the FTP log that stores the session detail or be able to get this from event viewer, etc. if possible and then trigger something for all files with a newer date modified attribute since the last run or something like that. Perhaps the list should be a date to check per each run or whatever when triggered and just update that list with that one value to check and update per each triggered run per the Event Viewer FTP session detail per mailbox or the FTP log or wherever that's at.

Comment: Just throwing out some ideas right now, I don't have time to try anything right now but maybe this will help or ring a bell for others with something similar they can test and post for you, etc.

Comment: Understand. Thanks for your guidance. I'll keep digging and see what I can turn up. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update for anybody interested.
Looking into using File Server Resource Manager to monitor this instead.

Raises another question, but I'll close this one now.